# Is this correct uint64_t compare?

Tags: c++, compare

I am experimenting with 3 way comparing 64 bit numbers, e.d. result must be similar to `memcmp` or `strcmp`.

I come up with this, but I can not be sure it will perform OK if I put some really big numbers.

Assembly looks great, but I am worried if is correct, since the compiler does not generate same code if I do it with branches.

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/UNtPGh

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>

int f(uint64_t a, uint64_t b){
    auto x = std::max(a, b);

    int xa = (x - a) > 0;
    int xb = (x - b) > 0;

    return xb - xa;
}

inline int f1(uint64_t a, uint64_t b){
    return f(b, a);
}

int main(){
    return f(550u, 5555u);
}
```

Comment: Did you test that the result is correct with edge values?

Comment: seems to work OK

Comment: You are worried because the compiler does not generate the same code when you provide it different code? Why is that surprising?

Comment: This is simple task, compiler usually understands it.

Comment: Why don't you express it `xa = x != a`, `(x-a)>0` seems to obfuscate what is done.

Comment: @AProgrammer Not sure I agree - you're adding a bit of cognitive load by introducing int->bool conversions. The shown code is a pretty idiomatic way of performing an integer "compare" function that results in "some neg number", "zero" or "some pos number"

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica, IMHO, the idiomatic way is the code in Nick's answer.  The one in the question, going through `max`, does not seems so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is variation on famous two argument `sgn` template code, but using `max`:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr int sgn(T a, T b){
    return (a > b) - (a < b);
}
```

and yes, it works for `uint64_t` and produce exact same assembly code.